# Error when using Binding in a Toggle Button: "Could not cast value of type 'CALayer' to 'SwiftUI.MaskLayer"

Tags: swiftui

I have a FeedbackView in SwiftUI that contains a couple of custom ToggleButtons. I have used these toggle buttons all throughout my App for a few months. The FeedbackView is new and is used in a couple of places in my App. When using the FeedbackView in one place in my App, complicated View with many components, the App crashes with an unhelpful stack trace and the error: "Could not cast value of type 'CALayer' (0x7fff87efafe0) to 'SwiftUI.MaskLayer".

Everything was working until I hooked up the binding for the selection state. I've never seen this error before and can't find any reference to it anywhere. Does anyone have any ideas on what it could be?

I've included some code, but I don't expect anyone to find the issue based upon it, more hoping someone has come across the error before and can get give me an idea on what can cause it.

Cut down version of FeedbackWidgetView

```
struct FeedbackWidgetView: View {

@State var positiveSelected : Bool = false
@State var negativeSelected : Bool = false

var body: some View {
    ZStack {                    
        if question.positiveButtonLabel != nil {
            ToggleButton(title: question.positiveButtonLabel!,
                         borderColor: .buttonBorderSecondary,
                         isSelected: $positiveSelected)
        }
    }
}
```

}

ToggleButton:

```
struct ToggleButton: View {

    var title : String
    var iconName : String? // SF Symbol Name
    var primaryColor : Color?
    var borderColor : Color?

    var unselectedStyle : ButtonLabel.Style = .primary
    var selectedStyle : ButtonLabel.Style = .primarySelected

    var action : ((String) -> Void)?

    @Binding var selected : Bool

    init(title: String,
         iconName: String?=nil,
         primaryColor: Color?=nil,
         borderColor: Color?=nil,
         unselectedStyle: ButtonLabel.Style = .primary,
         selectedStyle: ButtonLabel.Style = .primarySelected,
         isSelected: Binding<Bool> = .constant(false),
         action: ((String) -> Void)?=nil) {
    
        self.title = title
        self.iconName = iconName
        self.primaryColor = primaryColor
        self.borderColor = borderColor
        self.unselectedStyle = unselectedStyle
        self.selectedStyle = selectedStyle
        self._selected = isSelected
        self.action = action
    }

    var body : some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.selected.toggle()
            self.action?(self.title)
        }) {
            ButtonLabel(title: title,
                        iconName: iconName,
                        primaryColor: primaryColor,
                        borderColor: borderColor,
                        style: selected ? selectedStyle : unselectedStyle)
                 .padding(1.0)
        }
    }
}
```

Stack Trace:
[image: Stack Trace Main Thread]

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue is caused by my ButtonLabel code that I didn't post. If I comment out the .mask(Capsule()) then I no longer get a crash. I found the issue by commenting out line by line until there was almost nothing left in my FeedbackView except a single toggle button. Then I commented out the call to ButtonLabel() and replaced it with Text("Hello") and no crash. Then I looked the ButtonLabel code and mask jumped out at me due to the error message I had received.

Now I just need to work out why that line doesn't work.

```
               Text(title)
                    .padding(.horizontal, 32.0)
                    .padding(.vertical, 13.0) // Makes overall button 44.0
                    .background(self.primaryColor)
                    .mask(Capsule())
```

Fixed, changed the last two lines:

```
               Text(title)
                    .padding(.horizontal, 32.0)
                    .padding(.vertical, 13.0) // Makes overall button 44.0
                    .background(Capsule().fill(self.primaryColor))
```